# Kaazing - durable subscriber not receiving messages from topic

Tags: android, jms, kaazing

I have android jms clients running on 5 devices. All devices get connected with Kaazing to make durable connection to a topic.

The problem is that at least 2 devices are unable to receive messages from topic. 1 started receiving messages after ten minutes. But the other one didnt.

(Both devices have been tested before and they used to receive messages instantly.)

Any ideas are welcome please.

Answer (score 0):

Please use official Kaazing Android demo from here : https://github.com/kaazing/java.client.tutorials.

And then create durable subscribers as follows :

```html
    Topic topic = (Topic) destination;
    TopicSubscriber subscriber;
    subscriber = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "yourSubscriberID");
```

Note : Please make sure you are using a broker that supports durable subscribers.